# Is there a way to use video capture/ read in opencv without it taking so long?

Tags: python, opencv

There is about a 10-20 second delay between when I run my program and when the web camera actually takes the image. Is there any way to speed up this process?

I have looked several places and haven't found a solution.

```
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

I just don't get what is taking these two lines of code so long to execute when I can take a picture with my webcam instantly through the normal camera application.

Comment: It usually does not take that long. Are you sure that it is `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`? Do you load any libraries / files other than `cv2` and `numpy` before running the command?

Comment: It's only cv2.VideoCapture(1) because the built in webcam is cv2.VideoCapture(0) and I am using an external webcam. I am importing more than that, but the line that is taking the long time is video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

Comment: @ Madmax007 there might be a delay of few frames (2 - 3 seconds). Please, make sure that your waitkey(1) that means 1 ms delay which is used for executing each frame in imshow function. However, the speed also execution might also depend upon your operating system memory. You can check and can modify your frames per second and few more webcam setting. I have provided the link for it and please have a look under "Member Function Documentation"  https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html . Hopefully it will help  you.

Comment: I am having the same problem, in my case, it takes close to a minute to execute. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

Ok so it took me a while but the problem was solved by switching the API. I changed the line of code:

```
  video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

to

```
  video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

by adding this, it now works instantly, removing the delay which was present before.

Comment: It did not work for me, I tried to read the auto-detected format which came out to be CAP_MSMF. `cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_MSMF)` did not solve the problem either.

Comment: Be aware that using this solution causes video_capture.read()` not to return the most recent frame (i.e., there will be a delay to reach the last available frame through a buffer), and also, you cannot use `cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0)`.